# Stop retrying connect to YARN resource manager after limited attempts in Java

Tags: apache-spark, client, hadoop-yarn

I am using the org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client API in Java to submit Spark application to YARN.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();

List<String> submitArgs = new ArrayList<>();

if (StringUtils.hasText(appName)) {
    submitArgs.add("--name");
    submitArgs.add(appName);
    sparkConf.setAppName(appName);
}
submitArgs.add("--jar");
submitArgs.add(appJarPath);

submitArgs.add("--class");
submitArgs.add(appMainClass);
System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");

sparkConf.setMaster("yarn")
       .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
       .set("spark.yarn.queue",queue);

ClientArguments clientArguments = new ClientArguments(submitArgs.toArray(new String[submitArgs.size()]));
Client client = new Client(clientArguments, sparkConf);
client.run();
```

I am trying to create a scenario when the client cannot connect to the resource manager, after so may attempts, it will timeout and throw back an exception. However, the client keeps retrying connecting to the YARN resource manager without any timeout. See below console output:

```
2018-09-18 14:20:25.046  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy    : Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
2018-09-18 14:20:27.600  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:20:29.603  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:20:31.600  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:20:33.607  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:20:35.608  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:20:37.619  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:20:39.620  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:20:41.623  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:20:43.633  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:20:45.632  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:21:18.665  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:21:20.676  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:21:22.679  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:21:24.686  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:21:26.691  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:21:28.695  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:21:30.697  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-09-18 14:21:32.708  INFO 10480 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client             : Retrying connect to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
...
```

What custom configuration I should do and how so that the retry will stop after a limited number of attempts or time?